# autocomplete() generating non-text output

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have an `autocomplete()` function connected to a MYSQL database.

The jquery is completely run of the mill:

```
$(function() {
    $(".choose_venue").autocomplete({
        source: "list_venues.php",
        minLength: 1
        });                
    });
```

...and if I manually add a query such as "list_venues.php?term=Ku" onto the URL of list_venues.php, then that page gives a appropriate response (such as the following):

[{"name":"Fonderie Kugler"},{"name":"Kulturhaus Helferei"},{"name":"Kunstraum Walcheturm"}]

So, a simple `input` such as the following *should* be working:

```
<input type="text" style="width:270px;" class="choose_venue"/>
```

However, the output I get is a window containing no text, but just a number of faint lines.

[image: Autocomplete fail]

I first thought that this might be something in my CSS, but the problem persists even when ALL css modifications have been removed.

My next thought was that it might be a browser issue (I use Safari), but Chrome behaves exactly the same way.

The only other idea I had was that the jquery files I was calling were out of date or that there was some other problem, but I tried multiple links and I always get the same result. As of my most recent attempts I am linking to the following files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

It appears that the number of these grey lines corresponds to the number of text values that should be returned. But beyond that, I have no idea what is causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autocomplete need JSON objects with `label` and `value` properties, for another you need to rebuild it.

```
$(function() {
  $(".choose_venue").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "list_venues.php",
        success: function(data) {
          // needed if response header not JSON
          data = JSON.parse(data);
          data = $.map(data, function (obj) {
                return obj.name
            });
          response(data);
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 1
  });
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but this code is not giving me any output at all...

Comment: do you have `header('Content-Type: application/json');` in your PHP?

Comment: That was the problem just now -- brilliant!